# Reduce Equation font size globally

Tags: math-mode, fontsize

I am writing a cheat sheet for the exam and I would like to reduce the font size of display maths equations to fit as many equations as possible. Also I would ideally like to line break long equations. The file was originally written in md and converted to tex using pandoc, so ideally changing options globally and not doing much manual typing would be in order.

So I have equations like this

```
[\
%some equation
\]
```

how can I make these equations break lines and reduce the size of these equations? Ideally by adding something into the preamble.

I know that solutions exist that change the font size on a case basis like `\begingroup\makeatletter\def\f@size{5}\check@mathfonts $$abc+xyz=44$$\endgroup` or `$ {\scriptstyle x^2 + 2xy + y^2} $` but I would like to change it globally.

Comment: Without seeing any code it is hard to help you ...

Comment: I hope you do not mean 'cheat sheet' in the literal sense!

Comment: @IanThompson Dont worry, we are allowed to take one into the exam

Comment: @Mensch sure, thats how it looks like https://www.overleaf.com/read/csjrpzmfbtxz but I guess I will edit the question to include a code sample